# exec-maven-plugin cannot correctly use arguments

Tags: maven, openldap, exec-maven-plugin

I try to execute a shell script(actually it is ldapmodify of OpenLDAP) with some arguments. This is how I did in pom.xml:

In Maven Profile I defined some values

```
<profile>
    <id>Linux-OpenLDAP</id>
         <activation>
             <os>
                  <family>Unix</family>
             </os>
         </activation>
    <properties>
        <OpenLdap.ClientTools.home></OpenLdap.ClientTools.home>
        <executable>/usr/local/bin/ldapmodify</executable>
        <argument>-a -x -h localhost -p 389 -D "cn=manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com" -f ${test-users.idif.path} -w secret</argument>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

This is how I use exec-maven-plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${executable}</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <commandlineArgs>${argument}</commandlineArgs>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Then after `mvn install`, I got this error:

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (default) @ entity-matching-bootstrap ---
/usr/local/bin/ldapmodify: invalid option -- ' '
ldapmodify: unrecognized option -
Add or modify entries from an LDAP server
```

If I run `/usr/local/bin/ldapmodify -a -x -h localhost -p 389 -D "cn=manager,dc=ibm,dc=com" -f /home/entity-matching/entity-matching-bootstrap/src/test/resources/test_users.ldif -w secret` directly in commnad line, it would succeed. So why the option is invalid during mvn install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you embed the `<commandlineArgs>` within the `<arguments>` section. Just remvoe the `<arguments>` section:

```
<configuration>
  <executable>${executable}</executable>
  <commandlineArgs>${argument}</commandlineArgs>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Holy...I am so careless. Thanks.